# Simplify my function (loop, array)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, loops

I have a function that is repeated a few times, and I believe it is possible to simplify and send variables from an array.

```
var i = masterdata.timing.split(',');
        var index = 0;
        for (index = 0; index < i.length; ++index) {
            $("#timing_" + i[index].trim()).prop('checked', true);
        }

    var i = masterdata.concern.split(',');
    var index = 0;
    for (index = 0; index < i.length; ++index) {
        $("#concern_" + i[index].trim()).prop('checked', true);
    }

    var i = masterdata.steps.split(',');
    var index = 0;
    for (index = 0; index < i.length; ++index) {
        $("#steps_" + i[index].trim()).prop('checked', true);
    }
```

Maybe just change the categories into a variable and send the catergories from an array?

```
var chkgroup = [
            'timing, concern, steps'
        ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your idea should work fine:

```
var i;
var index = 0;
var j = 0;
var chkgroup = ['timing', 'concern', 'steps'];
var currentGroup;

for (j = 0; j < chkgroup.length; ++j) {
    currentGroup = chkgroup[j];

    i = masterdata[currentGroup].split(',');

    for (index = 0; index < i.length; ++index) {
        $("#" + currentGroup + "_" + i[index].trim())
            .prop('checked', true);
    }        
}
```

If the `chkgroup` array really matches the object `keys` in `masterdata`, you could use an outer `for..in` loop instead:

```
var i;
var index = 0;
var currentGroup;

for (currentGroup in masterdata) {
    i = masterdata[currentGroup].split(',');

    for (index = 0; index < i.length; ++index) {
        $("#" + currentGroup + "_" + i[index].trim())
            .prop('checked', true);
    }        
}
```

Note that there's no order defined for `for...in`, so if you need to guarantee that you're iterating over the object properties in a certain order, it might be better to use the predefined array.

You could also get fancy with `$.map`:

```
var values = $.map(masterdata, function (i, currentGroup) {
    return $.map(i.split(','), function (val) {
        return $('#' + currentGroup + '_' + val.trim());
    });
});

$(values).prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: in var i, masterdata.timing changes with the categories.

Comment: @triplethreat77: Updated, please take a look

Answer (score 0):

```
var chkgroup = [ 'timing', 'concern', 'steps' ];

setProps( chkgroup, masterdata );

function setProps( c, m ) {
    $.each(c, function(i, group) {
        var i = m[group]split(',');
        var index = 0;
        for (index = 0; index < i.length; ++index) {
            $("#" + group + "_" + i[index].trim()).prop('checked', true);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact your code is still a bit noisy and not readable, i.e. developer has to spend at least a few minutes analyzing it in order to understand if logic is correct. With the usage of loDash or Underscore, your code can be simplified and turn into this:

```
   var selector = _.chain(masterdata)
        //pick only needed items 
        .pick(masterdata, 'timing', 'concern', 'steps')
        .map(function (item, key) {
            //split and transform the string into selector, e.g. #timing_1
            var ids = item.split(',');
            var mapped = _.map(ids, function (id) { return "#" + key + "_" + id.trim(); });
            return mapped.join();
        })
        .value()
        .join();
    $(selector).prop('checked', true);
```

And working sample on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zv91ffh7/1/)